# How to do this operations about zeros?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have this table :

```
0001
003
02
1234
0012
```

And I would like to modify this table like this

```
1000
300
20
1234
1200
```

I mean if there is a zero in front of a number I would like to put it at the right e.g. 0012 will become 1200

Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: What to do if the value contains only zeros?

Answer (score 4):

You can use string operations:

```
select v.*,
      stuff(col, 1, patindex('%[^0]%', col) - 1, '') + left(col, patindex('%[^0]%', col) - 1)
from (values ('0001'), ('003'), ('02'), ('1234')) v(col)
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You know, it's not that easy to gain SQL reputation when you live in the same time zone as Gordon. Sigh.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yeah, and believe me I count my blessings every day I wake up, when I know Gordon is going to sleep.  But, for me it's a double-edged sword, because during business hours in Asia, we don't quite get the volume you get in the US/UK.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 4 zeros at the end and extract the substring starting from 1-9:

```
SELECT test, SUBSTRING(test + '0000', patindex('%[1-9]%', test), LEN(test))
FROM (VALUES
    ('0001'),
    ('003'),
    ('02'),
    ('1234'),
    ('0012')
) AS tests(test)
```

To handle tricky edge cases use:

```
SUBSTRING(test + '0000', ISNULL(NULLIF(patindex('%[1-9]%', test), 0), 1), LEN(test))
```